# Texture Buffers and glMultiDrawElements

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, jogl

Backstory:
I'm trying to draw as many squares the the screen as possible using a single draw call. I'm using a custom glsl vertex shader that is specialized for 2D drawing, and that is supposed to be pulling position data for the vertices of the squares from a samplerBuffer. Since I don't need to worry about rotating or scaling the squares all I should need to do is load the position data into a buffer, bind a texture to that buffer, and then use the sampler to get each vertex's position in the shader. In order to get an index into the texture I store each elements index as the z-component of the vertices.

Everything seems to work really well for a thousand or so squares, but after that I start to get weird blinking. It sort of seems like it's not drawing all of the squares every draw step, or possibly not using all of the positions so that many of the squares are overlapping.

The weird thing is, that if I use drawElements instead of drawElementsMulti, the blinking goes away (but of course then all the squares are drawn as one single object, which I don't want)

One question I have is if my position data is limited to the max texture size, or the max texture buffer size. And if I am limited to the much smaller max texture size, how do I get around it? There's got to be a reason all of that texture buffer space is there, but I obviously don't get how to properly use it.

I'm also thinking maybe glMultiDrawElements is doing something I'm not accounting for with the sampler somehow. Idk, I'm really lost at this point, and yet..it works perfectly for smaller numbers of squares, so I must be doing something right.

[EDIT] Code had changed to reflect suggestions below (and for readability), but the problem persists.

Ok, so here's some code. First the vertex shader:

```
uniform mat3 projection;
attribute vec3 vertex;

uniform samplerBuffer positionSampler;

attribute vec4 vertex_color;
varying vec4 color;

float positionFetch(int index)
{
    // I've tried texelFetch here as well, same effect
    float value = texelFetchBuffer(positionSampler, index).r;
    return value;
}

void main(void)  
{ 
    color = vec4(1, 1, 1, 1);
    // use the z-component of the vertex to look up the position of this instance in the texture
    vec3 real_position = vec3(vertex.x + positionFetch(int(vertex.z)*2), vertex.y + positionFetch(int(vertex.z)*2+1), 1); 
    gl_Position = vec4(projection * real_position, 1); 
}
```

And now my GLRenderer, sorry there is so much code, I just really want to make sure there's enough info here to get an answer. This has really been driving me nuts, and examples for java seem to be hard to come by (maybe this code will help someone else on their quest):

```
public class GLRenderer extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener, WindowListener
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8513201172428486833L;

    private static final int bytesPerFloat = Float.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;
    private static final int bytesPerShort = Short.SIZE / Byte.SIZE;

    public float viewWidth, viewHeight;
    public float screenWidth, screenHeight;

    private FPSAnimator animator;

    private boolean didInit = false;

    JFrame the_frame;
    SquareGeometry geometry;

    // Thought power of 2 might be required, doesn't seem to make a difference
    private static final int NUM_THINGS = 2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2; 

    float[] position = new float[NUM_THINGS*2];

    // Shader attributes
    private int shaderProgram, projectionAttribute, vertexAttribute, positionAttribute;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        new GLRenderer();
    }

    public GLRenderer()
    {
        // setup OpenGL Version 2
        super(new GLCapabilities(GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2)));

        addGLEventListener(this);
        setSize(1800, 1000);

        the_frame = new JFrame("Hello World");
        the_frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        the_frame.setSize(the_frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize());
        the_frame.setVisible(true);
        the_frame.addWindowListener(this);

        animator = new FPSAnimator(this, 60);
        animator.start();
    }

    // Called by the drivers when the gl context is first made available
    public void init(GLAutoDrawable d)
    {        
        final GL2 gl = d.getGL().getGL2();
        IntBuffer asd = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE, asd);
        System.out.println(asd.get(0));
        asd = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl.glGetIntegerv(GL2.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, asd);
        System.out.println(asd.get(0));
        shaderProgram = ShaderLoader.compileProgram(gl, "default");
        gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

        _getShaderAttributes(gl);

        gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        _checkGLCapabilities(gl);
        _initGLSettings(gl);

        // Calculate batch of vertex data from dirt geometry
        geometry = new SquareGeometry(.1f);
        geometry.buildGeometry(viewWidth, viewHeight);
        geometry.finalizeGeometry(NUM_THINGS);

        geometry.vertexBufferID = _generateBufferID(gl);
        _loadVertexBuffer(gl, geometry);

        geometry.indexBufferID = _generateBufferID(gl);
        _loadIndexBuffer(gl, geometry);

        geometry.positionBufferID = _generateBufferID(gl);

        // initialize buffer object
        int size = NUM_THINGS * 2 * bytesPerFloat;
        System.out.println(size);

    IntBuffer bla = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
    gl.glGenTextures(1, bla);
    geometry.positionTextureID = bla.get(0);

        gl.glUniform1i(positionAttribute, 0);

        gl.glActiveTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, geometry.positionTextureID);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, geometry.positionBufferID);
        gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, size, null, GL2.GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        gl.glTexBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL2.GL_R32F, geometry.positionBufferID);
    }

    private void _initGLSettings(GL2 gl)
    {
        gl.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
    }

    private void _loadIndexBuffer(GL2 gl, SquareGeometry geometry)
    {
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.indexBufferID);
        gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, bytesPerShort*NUM_THINGS*geometry.getNumPoints(), geometry.indexBuffer, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    private void _loadVertexBuffer(GL2 gl, SquareGeometry geometry)
    {
        int numBytes = geometry.getNumPoints() * 3 * bytesPerFloat * NUM_THINGS;

        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.vertexBufferID);
        gl.glBufferData(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, numBytes, geometry.vertexBuffer, GL2.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        gl.glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttribute);
        gl.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttribute, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    }

    private int _generateBufferID(GL2 gl)
    {
        IntBuffer bufferIDBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
        gl.glGenBuffers(1, bufferIDBuffer);

        return bufferIDBuffer.get(0);
    }

    private void _checkGLCapabilities(GL2 gl)
    {
        // TODO: Respond to this information in a meaningful way.
        boolean VBOsupported = gl.isFunctionAvailable("glGenBuffersARB") && gl.isFunctionAvailable("glBindBufferARB")
                && gl.isFunctionAvailable("glBufferDataARB") && gl.isFunctionAvailable("glDeleteBuffersARB");

        System.out.println("VBO Supported: " + VBOsupported);
    }

    private void _getShaderAttributes(GL2 gl)
    {
        vertexAttribute = gl.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "vertex");
        projectionAttribute = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection");
        positionAttribute = gl.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "positionSampler");
    }

    // Called by me on the first resize call, useful for things that can't be initialized until the screen size is known
    public void viewInit(GL2 gl)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < NUM_THINGS; i++)
        {
            position[i*2] = (float) (Math.random()*viewWidth);
            position[i*2+1] = (float) (Math.random()*viewHeight);
        }

        gl.glUniformMatrix3fv(projectionAttribute, 1, false, Matrix.projection3f, 0);

        // Load position data into a texture buffer
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, geometry.positionBufferID);
        ByteBuffer textureBuffer = gl.glMapBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL2.GL_WRITE_ONLY);
        FloatBuffer textureFloatBuffer = textureBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < position.length; i++)
        {
            textureFloatBuffer.put(position[i]);
        }

        gl.glUnmapBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable d)
    {

        if (!didInit || geometry.vertexBufferID == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        //long startDrawTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        final GL2 gl = d.getGL().getGL2();

        gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


        // If we were drawing any other buffers here we'd need to set this every time
        // but instead we just leave them bound after initialization, saves a little render time
        // No combination of these seems to fix the problem
        //gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.vertexBufferID);
        //gl.glVertexAttribPointer(vertexAttribute, 3, GL2.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        //gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, geometry.indexBufferID);
        gl.glBindBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, geometry.positionBufferID);
        //gl.glActiveTexture(GL2.GL_TEXTURE0);
        //gl.glTexBuffer(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL2.GL_R32F, geometry.positionBufferID);

        _render(gl, geometry);

        // Also tried these
        //gl.glFlush();
        //gl.glFinish();
    }

    public void _render(GL2 gl, SquareGeometry geometry)
    {
        gl.glMultiDrawElements(geometry.drawMode, geometry.countBuffer, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, geometry.offsetBuffer, NUM_THINGS);
        // This one works, but isn't what I want
        //gl.glDrawElements(GL2.GL_LINE_LOOP, count, GL2.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable d, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        final GL2 gl = d.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float) height / width;

        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;
        viewWidth = 100;
        viewHeight = viewWidth * ratio;

        Matrix.ortho3f(0, viewWidth, 0, viewHeight);

        if (!didInit)
        {
            viewInit(gl);
            didInit = true;
        } 
        else
        {
            // respond to view size changing
        }
    }
}
```

The final bit is the SquareGeometry class which holds all the bufferIDs and vertex data, but also is responsible for filling the vertex buffer correctly so that each vertex's z component can function as an index into the position texture:

```
public class SquareGeometry
{
    public float[] vertices = null;

    ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    IntBuffer countBuffer;
    PointerBuffer offsetBuffer;
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

    public int vertexBufferID = 0;
    public int indexBufferID = 0;
    public int positionBufferID = 0;
    public int positionTextureID = 0;

    public int drawMode;

    protected float width = 0;
    protected float height = 0;

    public SquareGeometry(float size)
    {
        width = size;
        height = size;
    }

    public void buildGeometry(float viewWidth, float viewHeight)
    {
        vertices = new float[4 * 2];
        vertices[0] = -width/2;
        vertices[1] = -height/2;
        vertices[2] = -width/2;
        vertices[3] = height/2;
        vertices[4] = width/2;
        vertices[5] = height/2;
        vertices[6] = width/2;
        vertices[7] = -height/2;

        drawMode = GL2.GL_POLYGON;
    }

    public void finalizeGeometry(int numInstances)
    {
        if(vertices == null) return;

        int num_vertices = this.getNumPoints();
        int total_num_vertices = numInstances * num_vertices;

        // initialize vertex Buffer (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)  
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(total_num_vertices * 3 * Float.SIZE);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++)
        {
            for(int v = 0; v < num_vertices; v++)
            {
                int vertex_index = v * 2;
                vertexBuffer.put(vertices[vertex_index]);
                vertexBuffer.put(vertices[vertex_index+1]);
                vertexBuffer.put(i);
            }
        }
        vertexBuffer.rewind();

        // Create the indices
        vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(total_num_vertices * Short.SIZE);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        indexBuffer = vbb.asShortBuffer();

        for(int i = 0; i < total_num_vertices; i++)
        {
            indexBuffer.put((short) (i));
        }
        indexBuffer.rewind();

        // Create the counts
        vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(numInstances * Integer.SIZE);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        countBuffer = vbb.asIntBuffer();
        for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++)
        {
            countBuffer.put(num_vertices);
        }
        countBuffer.rewind();

        // create the offsets
        offsetBuffer = PointerBuffer.allocateDirect(numInstances);
        for(int i = 0; i < numInstances; i++)
        {
            offsetBuffer.put(num_vertices*i*2);
        }
        offsetBuffer.rewind();
    }

    public int getNumPoints() 
    {
        return vertices.length/2;
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple more notes: I didn't post the matrix class that handles creating the projection matrix so you'll just have to trust me on that one. Also, glGetError returns all 0's :(

Comment: check also -Djogl.debug.TraceGL -Djogl.debug.DebugGL

Comment: wow, thanks so much for that. Lots of output here, already see a few things I was doing wrong, but so far no miracle fixes.

Comment: I just added gl.glFlush(); and gl.glFinish(); to the end of the draw, which I believe is opengl's way of doing vsync, didn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: You are using GLEventListener, so swapBuffers will be called without glFlush etc

Comment: vsync is about gl.setSwapInterval, but probably not the problem here

Comment: it's the same with or without glFlush/Finish but messing with the frame rate definitely does seem to have an effect o.0

Comment: oddly glSwapInterval(1) and no flush/finish gives me the best results so far, though I still seem to have issues if I pump the number of squares up high enough.

Comment: try reorder

    shaderProgram = ShaderLoader.compileProgram(gl, "default");
    _getShaderAttributes(gl);
    gl.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

Comment: and try to use newest (jogl "beta"s are very stable) library

Comment: Yeah, I already reordered those, I'm going to update the code in the question right now. I tried setting glSwapInterval(60) so that it's the same as my frame rate and everything seems to be golden (though I'm not totally sure yet). Is that actually how setSwapInterval is supposed to be used? Sorry if I'm asking dumb questions, but google does not seem to bring up much in the way of info for this.

Comment: 0 - disable, 1 - vsync, other - custom

Comment: I've still got some other issues where at some point it just won't draw any more squares (program doesn't crash, it just clearly draws less squares than it should) but the blinking is gone and I call that a win. If you want to submit an answer saying "throw a glSetSwapInterval(60) in your init and a glFlush/finish at the end of your draw" I will accept it. You helped me a ton here, thank you.

Comment: the problem is not solved yet.. and glSetSwapInterval should not be an issue. did u tried to load latest jogl build? the problem can be an already fixed old bug.

Comment: I was kind of avoiding it, but I suppose I can go grab the latest. The build I'm running on isn't that old at all though.

Comment: grabbed jogamp-all-platforms.7z from http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/ and the problem remains.

Comment: just grabbed latest release candidate to be extra sure. Still having the same issue.

Comment: I'm fairly positive it has something to do with the minimum texture size. The maximum amount of data I can fit into the texture buffer before the blinking starts happens to be the max texture size...I just don't understand why this is an issue. I'm clearly able to access more data than is represented by the minimum texture size...just not consistently. It's like opengl isn't reserving the memory for me or something. I tend to get more blinking when I mouse over the window title or task bar...definitely something funky going on here.

Comment: and now I think it's my ShortBuffer holding the vertex indices...idk, obviously I'm pretty stumped. I'll check back on this tomorrow. Considering switching to some really inefficient drawArrays calls just to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Just so you know, the `gl.glUniform1i(positionAttribute, 0);` means as you said that GL_TEXTURE0 is mapped to that sampler. This can be omitted if you order your samplers in the code as the mapping follows the order of definition. (Is not guaranteed though.)

Comment: m.b. it's worth trying (glcanvas/glwindow).setAutoSwapBufferMode(false) and swapping buffers manually at the end of a frame

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this, but unfortunately manually swapping buffers didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've got it solved, though I'm still really not clear on what the original problem was. I fixed it by simplifying the drawing to use drawArrays instead of drawElements or multiDrawElements. I'm really not sure why I thought I needed them, as I really don't in this case. I'm pretty sure I was messing up a few things with the indexes and offsets.

Furthermore, as far as the proper way to bind the texture buffer, neither the code I have above, nor example found at the link I posted in a comment are correct at all.

If anyone is interested in the correct way to use the texture buffer like this I just did a pretty extensive write-up on it here http://zebadiah.me/?p=44. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first things first, you are not setting gl_Color in the shader maybe that can be the issue here and you only lucky with small numbers. It is a varying, but do you also have fragment shader that picks up the value?

At no point do you ensure that NUM_THINGS*2 < GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE. I don't know how FloatBuffer.put reacts; being Java probably / hopefully an exception.

Also you bind the positionBufferID buffer, then unbind it but never rebind it.

You create positionTextureID but never put any data there. This also what you put into the sampler positionSampler and try to access.

Yea well lots of issues but my gut tells me the last one may be the real issue here.

Comment: There is also a fragment shader that does nothing but set the color, so that's not it. I completely agree on the GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE thing but I'm hoping you can explain why I'm limited by that, or rather, how to get around it. I'd like to develop a method such that I can use the entire GL_MAX_TEXTURE_BUFFER_SIZE. Rebinding the positionBufferID doesn't fix the problem, and I'm not really convinced it's necessary. I thought that I was providing data for the texture by pointing TEXTURE0 at the positionBufferID buffer via gl.glTexBuffer. Is this not the case? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I can't say it for sure; don't have Java on my machine ;-) but you have no data in the texture. Unless you can show me where positionTextureID is filled with data, I think that is your problem.

Comment: But how do I put data in it? I'm working from this example http://www.jotschi.de/?p=424 where similarly the actual texture never seems to be used, other than with glTexBuffer. Again, isn't that where the data comes from? I fill the positionBuffer, and I tell positionTexture to use that buffer? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: You need to remember that openGL is a state machine. The current operation is always affected of the state. In the link you posted, on line 176 the magic happens. The texture is created, then bound, then associated to the buffer. The glTexBufferExt works, because it binds to the current active texture. After line 94 in GLRender you need to call the glTexBuffer(Ext) function.